# Problem with dataContext it doesn't show in datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, datacontext

It seems that I have problem in `dataContext`. Let's say that I have a class `tblPerson` generated by Entity Framework in a database-first approach.

Something like this:

```
public partial class tblPerson
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And I also have a `PersonRepository` like this:

```
public class PersonRepository
{
    private readonly PersonEntities _dbContext;

    public PersonRepository(PersonEntities dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public IEnumerable<tblPerson> GetAllPeople()
    {
        return _dbContext.tblPersons.ToList();
    }
}
```

Now this is my `MainViewModel`:

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly PersonRepository _personRepository;
    private ObservableCollection<tblPerson> _peopleList;

    public ObservableCollection<tblPerson> PeopleList
    {
        get { return _peopleList; }
        set
        {
            _peopleList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(PeopleList));
        }
    }

    public MainViewModel(PersonRepository personRepository)
    {
        _personRepository = personRepository;
        LoadPeople();
    }

    private void LoadPeople()
    {
        var people = _personRepository.GetAllPeople();
        PeopleList = new ObservableCollection<tblPerson>(people);
    }
}
```

Is it better to say I change `app.xaml.cs` to this:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private IUnityContainer _container;

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        _container = new UnityContainer();
        _container.RegisterType<Test_EmployeeEntities>();
        _container.RegisterType<PersonRepository>();
        _container.RegisterType<MainViewModel>();

        //var mainWindow = new MainWindow(_container.Resolve<MainViewModel>());
        var mainWindow = _container.Resolve<MainWindow>();
    }
}
```

and also change `MainWindow.xaml.cs` for dataContext:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    // Default constructor (without parameters)
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // Constructor expecting MainViewModel
    public MainWindow(MainViewModel mainViewModel) : this()
    {
        DataContext = mainViewModel;
    }
}
```

And finally, this is the dataGrid in the view:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding PeopleList}" AutoGenerateColumns="True"/>
```

The problem is when I start it, I have `Count=4` for `PeopleList` and also `DataContext` but there is nothing in the dataGrid. Any help?

Comment: How do you show the Window?. There is no `mainWindow.Show()`. Looks like MainWindow is actually created via the default constructor. Have you put a break point inside both constructors of MainWIndow to see if and how often the constructora get invoked? It's recommended to not override the OnStartup, but instead register an Application.Startup event handler in the App.xaml. And better call `MainViewModel.LoadPeople` from the `MainWindow.Loaded` event and not from the constructor (that's always a bad idea).